# Message Queue: Which one is the best scenario?

Tags: web-crawler, message-queue

I write a web crawler.

The crawler has 2 steps:

1. get a html page
2. then parse the page

I want to use message queue to improve performance and throughput.

---

I think 2 scenarios:

### scenario 1:

```
    structure: 
    urlProducer -> queue1 -> urlConsumer -> queue2 -> parserConsumer
```

urlProducer: get a target url and add it to queue1

urlConsumer: according to the job info, get the html page and add it to queue2

parserConsumer: according to the job info, parse the page

### scenario 2:

```
    structure:
    urlProducer -> queue1 -> urlConsumer
    parserProducer-> queue2 -> parserConsumer
```

urlProducer : get a target url and add it to queue1

urlConsumer: according to the job info, get the html page and write it to db

parserProducer: get the html page from db and add it to queue2

parserConsumer: according to the job info, parse the page

---

There are multiple producers or consumers in each structure.

scenario1 likes a chaining call. It's difficult to find the point of problem, when occurring errors.

scenario2 decouples queue1 and queue2. It's easy to find the point of problem, when occurring errors.

I'm not sure the notion is correct.

Which one is the best scenario?  Or other scenarios?

Thanks~

Comment: I think this question should be moved to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic because it's in line with `software architecture and design` as one of the topics on programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Scenario 1 is your best option as you don't have to monitor a database, which could slow things down.  Not sure what you plan on using to implement this, but I could see it done couple different ways:

1. Using Kafka and laying out the consumers as you specified.
2. Using storm and not relying on a message queue.  Essentially, you are doing stream processing.

There are other ways you can do this (web services, embedded queue's like ZeroMQ, other brokers, etc.), but since you mentioned throughput, those are two of the scenarios that would give you good throughput.

Answer (score 1):

The second scenario would be a better way to handle this problem if you want to use a simple messaging system, in my opinion. The three key tasks that you have implemented are fetching links, fetching pages from the links and parsing them to get required information. We need to keep in mind that the rates at which these operations are performed are  different depending upon the size of the page being fetched. You would be better off having an intermediate storage to avoid clogging of the queueing systems.

That being said, I agree with @[blockcipher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/290541/blockcipher)'s answer on this thread to use Storm Clusters instead of the simple queueing mechanisms. Storm worker nodes can also define flow control methods for you to vary the rates of flow of the different streams on an average rate. In such a case, the first scenario would be more beneficial. So, your choice would depend upon what you are planning to use for implementing your solution.